# Versions - how to add all new files

Tags: svn, versions

I am using Versions application for Mac Os.

I am new to Versions. I have got a project that I modified recently - added a bunch of new files. Currently I manually add all new files into the repository (I have to expand all those folders with a yellow bead sign and select new files while holding APPLE key).

Is there a way to automatically add all new files from a certain folder into repository(if the folder itself is already under version control)?

Thanks.

Comment: What software are you using here? Subversion alone doesn't give you any graphical interface, only a command line one; you must have something else as well.

Comment: He is clearly using Versions, as per his text.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You should just skip using Versions for this task. Simply open your terminal and cd into that directory and issue:

```
svn add *
svn commit -m 'Adding a file'
```

then you are done.

Comment: This is a useful work around, but it doesn't answer the question as asked for future reference.

Comment: Save yourself the trouble and skip this answer. Read http://stackoverflow.com/a/12904983/129202

Answer (score 3):

Select the topmost folder with the blue ? next to it, and choose Action > Add Item (command-option-A).  That will recursively add everything in that folder.

Comment: My advice is to click 'Changed' instead of 'All' by `Show` on the right (below the Revert / Add / Delete buttons).  This will highlight which files are, in fact, not yet added to the repository.

Comment: I was having issues that the folder was already under version control and couldn't be added, after reading [this article](http://chrislee.kr/wp/2010/09/23/i-cant-add-a-directory-because-subversion-says-its-already-under-version-control/) I removed all .svn files (I checked they were there by [showing hidden files](http://osxdaily.com/2009/02/25/show-hidden-files-in-os-x/)) and it worked!

Answer (score 3):

1. Click "Changed" (under the Revert/Add/Delete buttons)
2. In the "Browse" tab/view, use command + A (to select all)
3. Click the "Add" button
4. Click the "Commit" button

Answer (score 0):

If you are using [Tortoise](http://tortoisesvn.tigris.org/) - you can simply go to the top folder and select "Commit" command - it should automatically detect new files and ask you if you want to add/commit

Eclipse plugin will do the same